# Man in mental asylum claims bomb is slowly destroying earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is what I remember from a story I read at least 40 years ago.

A man in a mental asylum claims a bomb (dropped half the world away?) is slowly destroying earth. In a few weeks the destruction caused by the bomb is spreading, according to the man, who is at first afraid and agitated, but is getting resigned as the destruction of earth, according to him, is getting closer. When the destruction of earth supposedly reaches him, the doctors find him dead.

Comment: Is there a bomb? Or is he just crazy? And if the latter, then how is this scifi or fantasy?

Comment: There is no bomb in our universe, but in his (the crazy man's) universe there is. At least that is how I interpreted the story.

Comment: I also remember the "crazy man" naming the lands that are destroyed, getting closer to him.